# How to make a class generic and correctly infer the return type of its method

Tags: python, solid-principles, python-typing

I'm trying to refactor some classes using SOLID principles in python, and I have a question about how to mix SOLID with python typing.

Suppose I have these classes:

```
from asyncpg import Pool


class PGQuery:
    async def execute(self, connection: Pool):
        raise NotImplementedError


class PGQueryExecutor:
    def __init__(self, connection: Pool):
        self._connection = connection

    async def execute(self, query: PGQuery):
        return await query.execute(self._connection)
```

and

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, parse_obj_as


class QualitySummary(BaseModel):
    count: int
    score: float


class PGQueryQualitySummary(PGQuery):
    def __init__(self, node: str):
        self.node = node

    async def execute(self, connection: Pool) -> QualitySummary:
        result = await connection.fetchrow(...)

        return parse_obj_as(QualitySummary, result)
```

Example usage:

```
pgqueryexecutor = PGQueryExecutor(...)
result = await pgqueryexecutor.execute(PGQueryQualitySummary(...))
```

The problem is that the inferred type for `result` is `Any`, which is the one of the base class `PGQuery`. I would like (maybe with generics?) that each subclass of `PGQuery` which implements its own `execute` method with its own return type is then correctly inferred by the `execute` method of the `PGQueryExecutor`, so the return value of:

```
pgqueryexecutor.execute(PGQueryAnySubclass(...))
```

is exactly the return type of `PGQueryAnySubclass.execute`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Which SOLID principle is this related to?

Comment: Single Responsibility and Open Closed.

Comment: Can you expound on that? How does this code demonstrate or violate those principles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using [generic protocol](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#id28), from which you can inherit specific query classes. An example is provided below. Take into account that type variable is used *covariantly* as a return type, therefore we marked it as `covariant=True` (more details on the link above).

```
from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import TypeVar, Protocol

from pydantic import BaseModel, parse_obj_as

T = TypeVar('T', covariant=True)


class Pool:
    ...


class PGQuery(Protocol[T]):
    @abstractmethod
    async def execute(self, connection: Pool) -> T:
        raise NotImplementedError


class PGQueryExecutor:
    def __init__(self, connection: Pool):
        self._connection = connection

    async def execute(self, query: PGQuery[T]) -> T:
        return await query.execute(self._connection)


class QualitySummary(BaseModel):
    count: int
    score: float


class PGQueryQualitySummary(PGQuery[QualitySummary]):
    def __init__(self, node: str):
        self.node = node

    async def execute(self, connection: Pool) -> QualitySummary:
        # ...
        return parse_obj_as(QualitySummary, {})


async def main() -> None:
    q = PGQueryQualitySummary("node")
    ex = PGQueryExecutor(Pool())
    reveal_type(await ex.execute(q))  # revealed type QualitySummary
```

Comment: It works great! Too bad IDEs like PyCharm still does not infere it correctly but it's an IDE problem...